# Upload APK Using Test fairy Plugin issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testfairy

I am uploading an apk file using **test fairy plugin**

But I am getting an error **the apk does not contain testfairy sdk android- Testfairy sdk integration android**.

How to integrate testfairy sdk with application?

I am following [this](http://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html) article url  but I am getting two exception

1. Java.lang.class.defounder
2. Null Pointer Exception android

Please Help !

Answer (score 2):

Adding the TestFairy SDK is easy, here are the details:
http://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html

If you have Proguard enabled, please add this snippet to your proguard rules file

-keep class com.testfairy.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.testfairy.**

-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, LineNumberTable